# Break out of promise chain running through multiple classes/methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rxjs6

Language: Typescript 3.5x

Environment: Angular 8.x, RxJS 6.x

I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of a chain of promises that looks (simplified) like this:

```
ClassA.methodA1 is called

 -methodA1 does an if/then check and if true, calls ClassB.methodB1

 --methodB1 calls a different function and combines the results with a parameter passed to it, and ultimately calls ClassC.methodC1

 ---methodC1 does some validation and then calls ClassD.methodD1 if valid

 ----methodD1 makes an async call (to a DB) and waits for it to finish before returning back the value it received (an ID).

When methodA1 receives the id, it calls ClassA.methodA2 and passes that Id in as a parameter
```

The method called by methodD1 is outside my control, and returns a Promise.  I can't change that.  However, I need methodA1 to wait until methodD1 is complete, and it receives the ID - each intervening method simply passes that return value back up to its caller.

Even this simplified version smells.  NONE of the intervening methods (methodB1 or methodC1, and there are actually 2 more in the real code) need to be async.  The only reason they are currently is that I need everything to wait until methodD1 finishes before continuing.  Each intervening method simply returns the Promise returned from the method it calls.

I refactored with async/await and while there is less code, it is still a series of methods that simply pass the return value they receive from a method call back up the chain, and it's still a bunch of unnecessary async/await on the intervening methods.

I refactored to RxJS Subjects and having methodA1 subscribe and then methodD1 call `.next(id)` when it is complete but this doesn't really feel any better.  I potentially have several dozen similar flows across my app and it feels like going the Subject route is a lot of extra plumbing overhead and keeping straight which subscription response belongs to which subscription instance is going to be problematic.

My gut tells me that the Subject route is the right approach, but I was wondering if there was something I was missing that makes it cleaner.  Is there some built-in mechanism to tag subscription responses to a given subscription instance so that the subscription code only processes the response to ITS call and then unsubscribes?

The only other approach I can think of, which is just plain **UGLY** is to pass my ClassA instance all the way down to ClassD and have ClassD call methodA2 when it receives the id from the DB.  But this is even worse.

Is there something I'm missing?  If so, what?  Any guidance or a pattern reference is appreciated.

Comment: `The only reason they are currently is that I need everything to wait until methodD1 finishes before continuing.` - Any function that *depends* on an asynchronous response is then itself asynchronous. It's a bit tough to give suggestions on such a high level generalized overview of your chain, but I don't see that much of an issue - just make those functions `async` and `await` each one like you're already doing, it doesn't get much cleaner than that imo. They aren't unnecessary since you need an asynchronous response.

Comment: I agree with the above, without specifics I think it is hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: @Klaycon, thanks.  What I meant was that the intervening methods don't depend on the async result, they just wait for the call to finish and then pass it back up the chain.  Only methodA1 actually needs/uses the async response. I hesitate to add detail as the next thing to add is a bunch of code - currently the contents of 4 files.  Is there specific detail besides that which would clarify things?  Basically, A calls B, B calls C, C calls D, D calls the DB.  A needs to wait until the DB call is complete before proceeding.

Comment: If the intervening methods don't use the result, why not do the DB call in A? Then you can keep B, C, and D synchronous and only A asynchronous.

Comment: B, C, and D do other things (validation, branching, etc) for this flow and others. Plus, the way I have things separated, only D ever interfaces with the DB

Comment: Well, what I'm noticing is that your main issue seems to be the fact that B and C don't need the value returned by D, only A does. I only really see two options then: either A calls D and thus B&C don't need to be async, or they all must be async as B and C must wait on D and that means they are by definition asynchronous functions.

Comment: This is the same conclusion I've come to, but it just feels wrong.  I'm trying to figure out if there's something better that I've overlooked.  Any thoughts on the RxJS Subject route?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with RxJS. It sounds more complicated than is necessary, but again it's hard to say with just the high level overview to go on.

Comment: "*NONE of the intervening methods need to be async*" - yes they do. They are calling other asynchronous methods, and they do return promises. That's what makes them async. "*I refactored with async/await and […] there is less code*" - how did the addition of the `async` keyword (and nothing else) lead to less code? There really should be only a tail-call to the promise-returning function. Maybe you can show/link the relevant bits of your actual code?

Comment: By adding async, I don't need to explicitly return the Promise, ie: 

return new Promise<blah>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
   ...do stuff...
});

Typescript handles generating that code, so it's less I need to maintain.

Also, the only reason the intervening methods are async is because D is.  They don't otherwise need to be, and that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input.  While the chain of promises is a legitimate approach, it just felt wonky, harder to test and reason about.  YMMV.

I ended up going a slightly modified route with RxJS Subjects.  The difference from what I had before is that the Subjects, instead of being permanent and hard-coded, are dynamically created as needed and stored in a Map.  Once they are no longer needed, they are deleted.  By giving each a distinct name, I don't need to verify which response "belongs" to which subscription - it is all keyed off of the distinct name as the key of the map.

The only thing I don't like about this approach is having to pass the distinct name all the way down the chain, but I can live with that.  Everything flows in one direction - "down" the chain - which is easier for me to reason about.

Here is the psuedo-code version of what I ended up with (all error-checking and class instantiation removed for brevity):

```
export class ClassA {
    methodA1(param1){
        if(someCondition){
            const theKey = this.generateUniqueKey();
            DispatcherInstance.subjects.set(theKey, new Subject<number>());
            const sub = DispatcherInstance.get(theKey).subscribe( (dbId: number) => {               
                    sub.unsubscribe();
                    DispatcherInstance.subjects.delete(theKey);
                    this.doNextStepWithId(dbId);                
            }
            classBInstance.methodB1(param1, theKey);
        }
    }
}

export class ClassB {
    methodB1(param1, theKey): void {
        const result = this.methodB2();
        classCInstance.methodC1(param1, result, theKey);
    }
}

export class ClassC {
    methodC1(param1, result, theKey): void {
        if(this.validate(param1, result)){
            ClassDInstance.methodD1(param1, theKey);
        }
    }
}

export class ClassD {
    methodD1(param1, theKey: string): void {
        db.someFunc(param1).then( (dbId: number) => {
            DispatcherInstance.subjects.get(theKey).next(dbId);
        });
    }
}

export class Dispatcher {
        const subjects: Map<string, Subject<number>> = new Map<string, Subject<number>>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only other approach I can think of is to pass my ClassA instance all the way down to ClassD and have ClassD call methodA2 when it receives the id from the DB. But this is even worse.

That's essentially a callback (with an instance receiving a method call, instead of a plain function getting called), is generally considered worse than simply returning promises.

Notice there is nothing wrong with your original approach, if only component D does calls to the database (which are asynchronous) and all the other modules depend on D because they do things that use the database, then the other modules naturally become asynchronous as well. The async (promise-returning) call being in a tail position seems like a coincidence then, and might change if the components are going to do multiple db calls in sequence.

However, there *is* another approach that you missed. It is applicable when all of your functions just do some combination/translation/validation of parameters, and in the end pass them into a different method. Instead of having B call C itself, it could simply return the validated parameters to A, and then let A call C directly. This will make B and C completely synchronous and unit-testable, and only A calls the asynchronous method of D.